# Copying records from one oracle database to another using python code

Tags: python, oracle, database-connection, cx-oracle

Could you please help me with the follwing request

I need to copy records from one oracle db ( production environment) to another ( test environment) using python code.

Oracle db version 11g

Could you  help me out.

Comment: Why use Python for this? Surely there are tools for dumping tables or databases into a file and also loading them. Using Python will make this process slower. Python is not ideal for "shelling out".

Comment: Exactly; consider Data Pump Export / Import (or the original EXP / IMP) utilities, or - if those base *see* each other (are in the same network), copy data over a database link. INSERT should be fairly fast.

Answer (score 0):

Check out odo blaze:

http://odo.pydata.org/en/latest/overview.html

It can handle data migration across many different data types and databases